# Perl calls java - How do I prevent an exception display?

Tags: java, perl, system, call

I have a perl CGI that calls a java application which in turn checks a Mysql database. If I search for an entry that does not exist, the java application displays an exception handler message on the server (requires an X display window). The exception is straight forward and understandable, however must be clicked to close it, at which point the perl CGI can continue. Customers of course cannot (and should not) see the exception message.

My question is.. how can I prevent the exception message from displaying on the server window and preventing the CGI from continuing? Is there a way to close the message from perl? I have control over the perl script, but not the java application I call.

$ENV{'DISPLAY'} = 'myserver:0.0';
$testline = system("java -Dby.product=true -jar javaApp.jar $version status>mytest.txt") >> 8;

if $version doesn't exist, I get the exception.
I pipe the results to a file for later file handling in perl

Thanks.
Rocky.

=====================

Thanks.
I added this...

```
$ENV{'DISPLAY'} = 'server:0.0';
use IPC::Open2;
use POSIX ":sys_wait_h";
$pid = open2(\*CHLD_OUT, \*CHLD_IN, "java -Dby.product=true -jar javaApp.jar $version status>mytest.txt 2>/tmp/java_error.$$"); 
sleep(5);
kill('TERM', $pid);
```

If I use a known value in the database, it works fine, as before.
If I search a nonexistent value, the java message still pops up.
Without the sleep line, the java message does NOT popup. In other words it looks like the pid is killed, but so quickly that the result does not get fed into mytest.txt. I thought the sleep function would give some time for the java app to work and then the kill would remove the popup message. But this does not happen.

It seems likely I will have to request changes to the java application so that it does not display a message on screen in the server.

Comment: try to include the database access at business logic in your perl cgi script (translate from java program)

Comment: If You use `Open2` used `waitpid` to wait it to finish. You do not have to kill the process.

Answer (score 1):

**Corrected and extended**

Try

```
system("java -Dby.product=true -jar javaApp.jar $version status 2>/dev/null >mytest.txt");
```

It redirects the `stderr` of `java` to nowhere. Or redirect to a file (like `2>/tmp/java_error.$$`) to save it debugging the error.

If it is on windows use `2>nul`.

Or use **[IPC::Open3](http://perldoc.perl.org/IPC/Open3.html)** and process both input file handles as You like.

More detailed. I created a simple `a.java` code which writes to stdout, stderr and throws an exception if an arg is defined:

```
public class a {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("STDOUT");
    System.err.println("STDERR");
    if (args.length > 0) { int i = 1/0; }
  }
};
```

I compiled and run it (don't care about the gcj warning):

```
$ gcj -C a.java
$ gij -cp . a
STDOUT
STDERR
$ gij -cp . a x
STDOUT
STDERR
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
   at a.main(a.java:5)
$ gij -cp . a >/dev/null
STDERR
$ gij -cp . a x 2>/dev/null
STDOUT
```

So the stack dump is written to the stderr as expected, so it can be redirected.

```
$ perl -e 'system("gij -cp . a x 2>/dev/null")' 
STDOUT
```

The example program with [IPC::Open3](http://perldoc.perl.org/IPC/Open3.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use IPC::Open3 'open3';
use Symbol 'gensym';

my ($fcin, $fcout, $fcerr);
$fcerr = gensym;
my $pid = open3 $fcin, $fcout, $fcerr, "gij -cp . a x";
my @out = <$fcout>;
my @err = <$fcerr>;
my $err = waitpid $pid, 0;
print "Exit:", ($err >> 8), "\n";
print "OUT: @out\n";
print "ERR: @err\n";
```

Output:

```
Exit:72
OUT: STDOUT

ERR: STDERR
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at a.main(a.java:5)
```

Even the man page of IPC::Open3 suggests to use the [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/IPC-Run-0.92/lib/IPC/Run.pm) package. I tried, but it is not the part of the normal distribution. So You can install it from CPAN if You wish.

Comment: Thanks. See my additions above. Seems likely I will have to have the java code altered.

Comment: @Rocky: Sorry if my description was not clear enough. You have either make redirection on the command line or use `Open2`. Using both is fairly pointless. But I'll check what is going on, because a program even can write directly to the terminal.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll mess around with this and implement your suggestions. I'll let you know what I end up with.

Comment: @Rocky: The Open2 was a bad guess, but Open3 seems to be okay. But if You do not really need the stdout and stderr, I suggest You to redirect them to `/dev/null` and use the `system` function.

Comment: @Rocky: OOPS! I think I misinterpreted your request! :( I thought You are bothered with the exception generated stack trace! But instead there is a message box, stating that the required version is not found (or alike). Your kill solution can be adequate for this.

Comment: What happen if the `DISPLAY` environment variable is not set, the java app fails to start?

Comment: Maybe this can help to make the messagebox invisible: http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/desktop-x-windows/1633-use-dummy-display.html